# Calculate concentration of product after time passed

Tags: concentration, reaction-order, rate-equation

If I have two parallel reactions:

A --> P$1$   (k$_1$ = $0.00010$  s$^{-1}$)

A --> P$2$   (k$_2$ =  $0.00050$  s$^{-1}$)

and know that the initial concentration of A is $0.0417$ M. How can I calculate the concentrations of P$1$ and P$2$ after $30$ min?

Thank you!

**EDIT**

I believe the downvote is because I haven't tried to solve the problem myself. This is because I have no idea how to do it. I can get a relationship between the two products:

dP$1$/dt = k$_1$[A]

dP$2$/dt = k$_2$[A]

=> dP$1$/dP$2$= k$_1$/k$_2$

Integrating gives:

k$_2$P$1$ = k$_1$P$2$ => $0.0005$P$1$ =$0.0001$P$2$ => P$1$ = $0.2$P$2$

But what I can do with this relationship I don't know since I don't know how to calculate the products.

Comment: **Hint**: You know from the two rate constants that the second product, P2, is produced at 5 times the rate of the first product, P1, so at any time you will have a 5 = P2/P1. So add the two rate constants, solve the rate equation, and use the ratio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kinetics is given by :
$\pu{d[A]/dt}$ = $\pu{- k_{1}[A] - k_{2}[A] = - k_t[A]}$

Integration gives : $\pu{[A] = [A]_{0} e^{-k_tt}}$

At any time, the proportion of $\pu{P_{1}}$ and $\pu{P_{2}}$ are $\pu{k_{1}/k_t}$ and $\pu{k_{2}/k_t}$

As a consequence, the wanted concentrations of $\pu{P_{1}}$  and $\pu{P_{2}}$ at time $t$ are the following :

$$\pu{[P_{1}] = \frac{k_{1}}{k_t} [A]_{0} ( 1 - e^{-k_t t} )}$$
$$\pu{[P_{2}] = \frac{k_{2}}{k_t} [A]_{0} ( 1 - e^{-k_t t} )}$$

In the present problem, $\pu{k_t = 0.00060 s^{-1}}$, $\pu{[A]_{0} = 0.0417 M }$, and $\pu{t = 1800 s}$, so that  $\pu{k_tt = 1.08}$

$$\pu{[P_{1}] = ( 1/6) · 0.0417 M · ( 1 - e^{-1.08}) = \frac{0.0417}{6} ( 1 - 0.340) = 0.0046 M }$$
$$\pu{[P_{2}] = ( 5/6) · 0.0417 M · ( 1 - e^{-1.08}) = \frac{5·0.0417}{6} ( 1 - 0.340) = 0.0023 M }$$